# How to plot results of repeated loop separately?

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, plot

I have code for a 1D random walk, that I need to run 20 times and plot the results in one graph. The code works correctly for 1 walk, but i cant work out how to do it for multiple walks.

I have tried a  while loop and a for loop, and for some reason it iterates over the loop and *adds* the results rather than going back to the beginning and starting again. So, if I have 100 steps and want to do this walk 20 times it plots one walk of 20*100=2000 steps, rather than 20 walks of 100 steps.
Here is my code:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

p=0.5
q=1-p
prob=[p,q]

N=100 #number of steps
n=20 #number of walks

start = 0  
positions = [start]
no_of_walks=list(range(0,n+1)) #since its a half open half closed interval

for n in no_of_walks:
    for i in range(0, N): 
        rr = random.random()
        right = rr < prob[0] and positions[-1] > -N
        left = rr > prob[1] and positions[-1] < N #length to be walked over 
        positions.append(positions[-1] - right + left)
        plt.plot(positions)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you considered resetting `positions` before each walk?

Comment: ah, thats a good tip! im trying it now by simply moving it inside the 1st for loop.

Answer (score 1):

`positions` needs to be reset before each walk, by moving it into the outer loop.

Furthermore, I assume each walk should be plotted only once, so the call to `plt.plot(...)` should go into the outer loop too (after the walk).

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

p=0.5
q=1-p
prob=[p,q]

N=100
n=20

start = 0  
#positions = [start]             # <- move this
no_of_walks=list(range(0,n+1))   #     |
                                 #     |
for n in no_of_walks:            #     v
    positions = [start]          # <- here
    for i in range(0, N): 
        rr = random.random()
        right = rr < prob[0] and positions[-1] > -N
        left = rr > prob[1] and positions[-1] < N
        positions.append(positions[-1] - right + left)
    plt.plot(positions)          # <- and move this out of the walk

plt.show()
```